# Map not showing current location with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm new to Android Development. I've used Navigation drawer as MainActivity, Maps Activity for MAP and have used GPSTracker java file  which I found in other question.

When I run app with Maps activity, it shows user current location but now with Navigation drawer, it run without any error but do not show current location.

Below is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
Button btnShowLocation;

// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;
private GoogleMap mMap;
double latitude;
double longitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    gps = new GPSTracker(MapsActivity.this);

    // check if GPS enabled
    if (gps.canGetLocation()){

        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();



        // \n is for new line
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        // can't get location
        // GPS or Network is not enabled
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("You are here").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.defaultico)));

    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    float zoomLevel = (float) 14.0; //This goes up to 21
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, zoomLevel));
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
}
}
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
Button btnShowLocation;

// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;
private GoogleMap mMap;
double latitude;
double longitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    gps = new GPSTracker(MapsActivity.this);

    // check if GPS enabled
    if (gps.canGetLocation()){

        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();



        // \n is for new line
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        // can't get location
        // GPS or Network is not enabled
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("You are here").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.defaultico)));

    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    float zoomLevel = (float) 14.0; //This goes up to 21
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, zoomLevel));
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


}


}
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/btnShowLocation"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />



<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

    />
```

**activity_navigation.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<include layout="@layout/activity_maps"/>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"

    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to show MyLocation in Google MAP:-

mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

if you do not want to use custom marker.

Comment: Your code is OK as I see. But try to use breakpoints that your onMapReady is calling or not.

Comment: No, it's not calling onMapReady. How can I do this? Sorry I am new just going through these small issues.

Comment: Note: getMapAsync() must be called from the main thread, and the callback will be executed in the main thread. If Google Play services is not installed on the user's device, the callback will not be triggered until the user installs Play services.

Comment: Follow the link:- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#add_map_code

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This : Just call this method and import what needs to be imported.

public void setMyLocation(){
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                    Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(this);
                    ArrayList<Address> addresses = null;
                    try {
                        addresses = (ArrayList<Address>) gCoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(), 1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "locaion : " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                }

                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                }

                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                }

                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                }
            };

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return null;
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }
```